# Energy estimate for $\theta_t + H(\theta)_x = 0$ in $t>0, x >0$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the IBVP for $$\theta_t + H(\theta)_x = 0, \qquad t>0, \ x>0$$ with $$H(\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{pv}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\theta(y)}{y-x} dy$$
with Dirichlet boundary conditions. Formally, how can one estiamte
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^\infty |\theta|^2 dx,$$
that is, one can one estimate $\int_0^\infty \theta H(\theta)_x dx$?

Comment: At first glance, this looks like $\theta_t = -(-\Delta)^{1/2} \theta$, where $\Delta$ is the 1-D Laplace operator (the second derivative), and where $\theta(t,x) = 0$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0]$ serves as the "boundary condition". If this is the case, the energy is non-increasing in time; in fact, $\theta(t, x) = \int \theta(s, y) p_{t-s}(x, y) dy$ for a symmetric Markovian kernel $p_t(x, y)$, and symmetric Markovian kernels define contractions on $L^p$ for every $p \in [1, \infty]$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks! What if we want to have a boundary condition at $x=0$ instead of on the whole half-line $(-\infty,0]$?

Comment: My understanding is as follows. You start with $\theta(t, \cdot)$ defined on $[0, \infty)$, equal to zero at $0$. You can artificially extend it to all of $\mathbb R$ so that it is zero in $(-\infty, 0]$. Then the domain of the integral in the definition of $H(\theta)$ can be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$, so that $H$ is the usual Hilbert transform. And now the $x$-derivative of the Hilbert transform is just $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$.